# How do I turn a laptop into a single-purpose word-processing appliance?

Tags: laptop, kiosk, single-user

I wish to turn a laptop into a device that does nothing but word-processing, with the option to save/load files from a usb thumb drive. The only way out of this mode would be with a password. The single-app mode should persist across reboots.

How can I use Ubuntu in "kiosk mode" to run only a word processor?

Comment: Things to consider that may make your task more complicated: Which application do you want to use? For example, if LibreOffice Writer, will you also want access to Calc?  Will you need to add a printer?  Is it a requirement that the WP can only open/save to a USB drive?

Comment: @Nmath — Additional functionality that comes with an office suite, such as LibreOffice, is fine. Printing is optional. Read/write to local disk, in addition to a USB drive, is also fine. I'm glad to consider any software application, including recommendations for inexpensive hardware on which to implement a solution.